# using node.js and found this error > 'server' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) > from "var server = app.listen(3000, listening);"

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, server

been doing the 8.6 in api2 folder but got this error/bug then I look at my server.js and found the error/bug then I go back to api1 folder which is the 8.5 lesson, I have finish the 8.5 lesson and it doing correctly by save to json file and read json file just fine, but for some reason this happen when I go back to my api1??

The Coding Train

8.5: Saving Data to JSON File with Node.js - Programming with Text

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zr8j-jeU_M&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Yyn-fBtGHfN0_xCtBwUkBp&index=6

The Coding Train

8.6: API Front End Client - Programming with Text

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zr8j-jeU_M&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Yyn-fBtGHfN0_xCtBwUkBp&index=6

PS:I have been using Safari and vscode

I think the error/bug start from when I write the **fs.writefile** by using **word or words** don't know I got confuse on why it got **different error** from the video but when I write all the code by adding **JSON.stringify** and I got it right? so I just ignore the error because I got it right and the code run just fine, so I move on to lesson 8.6 then I got the error when I try to write the code from 8.6

or maybe I did not code correctly? I went to **other code** and I found the same error but not on

```js
// This call back just tells us that the server has started
function listen() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
}
```

but on

```js
// Callback
function showAll(req, res) {
  // Send the entire dataset
  // express automatically renders objects as JSON
  res.send(words);
}
```

When I point my mouse on req it got the same error/bug **'req' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)**

**this is the website that I got the source code from**

https://shiffman.net/a2z/server-node/

**this is the other code**

https://github.com/Programming-from-A-to-Z/A2Z-F16/blob/gh-pages/week4-node/06_save_JSON/server.js

//

**This is my error/bug on project "api1" folder**

```js
var server = app.listen(3000, listening);
```

**var server: Server**

**'server' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)**

//

**this is my file and folder**

api1 //folder

node_modules //**express folder**

package-lock.json //file

**package.json** //file

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "name": "project-pj",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  }
}
```

**server.js** //file

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('words.json');
var words = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(words);

//console.log('server is starting');

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var server = app.listen(3000, listening);

function listening () {
    console.log("listening...");
}

app.use(express.static('website'));

app.get('/add/:word/:score?', addWord);

function addWord(request, response) {
    var data = request.params;
    var word = data.word;
    var score = Number(data.score);
    var reply;
    if (!score) {
       var reply = {
            msg: "Score is required."
        }
        response.send(reply);
    } else{
        words[word] = score;
        var data = JSON.stringify(words, null, 2);
        fs.writeFile('words.json', data, finished);

        function finished(err) {
            console.log('all set.');
            reply = {
                word: word,
                score: score,
                status: "success"
            }

            response.send(reply);
        }
        
    }

}

app.get('/all', sendAll);

function sendAll(request, response) {
    response.send(words);
}

app.get('/search/:word/', searchWord);

function searchWord(request, response) {
    var word = request.params.word;
    var reply;
    if (words[word]) {
        reply = {
            status: "found",
            word: word,
            score: words[word]
        }
    } else {
        reply = {
            status: "not found",
            word: word
      }
    }
response.send(reply);
}
```

website //folder

index.html //file

**words.json** //file

```js
{
  "rainbow": 5,
  "unicorn": 3,
  "doom": -3,
  "gloom": -2,
  "purple": 3,
  "pink": 6,
  "flower": 7
}
```

Comment: _"'server' is declared but its value is never read"_ - that's true, isn't it? Please note that most of your snippets cannot actually run in a browser environment - [edit] your question to fix the formatting.

Comment: Are you using ESLint? If so, it may just be a syntax error in which ESLint tells you there is no point in defining `server` if you don't read it.

Comment: then can you write in code? cause I new at using node.js and I don't even know what I'm missing All I know is step 1 use terminal open vscode, step 2 write code, step 3 start a server 3000 by using the terminal... which is in the video of 8.5

Comment: @Mastermind I just use ESlint, didn't solve my bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401985/server-is-declared-but-its-value-is-never-read-ts6133-with-eslint-still

Comment: If you simply want to fix the problem: app.listen(3000, listening) this is a linter problem, and it likely won’t affect the result of the code. A linter only manages your code style, and likely won’t have a big impact on the outcome of the code (generally)

Answer (score -2):

Finally after 1 month of going back and forth, I finally understand the express and how to save data by remove the **Bug**, for some reason I got this line of code that I don't even remember why I add it in the first place... probably too much coffee LOL

sketch.js "File"

```js
const { text } = require("express");//bug right here

function setup() {
createCanvas(400, 400);
background(51);
loadJSON('all', gotData);
console.log('running');
}

function gotData(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var keys = Object.keys(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var word = keys[i];
    var score = data[word];
    var x = random(width);
    var y = random(height);
    fill(255);
    textSize(64);
    text(word, x, y);
  }
}
```

Thank to this info I got to know a lot more about express and where to put all my **Game Code** to the **Public** folder, guess I should start with **"2.1 Server-side with Node.js"** first to understand "express and server side" but oh well, I just want to save data and I got it, and just finish the 8.6 and now I'm in 8.7 LOL Api is harder than I thought, at first I though it was some kinda code to work with other website, but now I know it was for save data and a lot more... :

```js
//ExpressStartInfo
/*
const express = require('express');//Start1
const app = express();//Start2
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));//Start3
//node index.js
//search for package.json "main">index.js

//public folder
//index.html file

//nodemon index.js

app.use(express.static('public'));//Start4
//Run the folder that have html Website/p5.js project in it
//app.use(express.static('public/P5.js'));
*/

//Server Side
//BackEnd
//index.js


//Source:
//2.1 Server-side with Node.js - Working with Data and APIs in JavaScript
//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxbQP1LMZsw


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//"sketch.js" bug
//const { text } = require("express"); //due to error of text not show up errase this//AKA "Bug"


//nodemon node server.js

//npm start
//http://localhost:3000


//End at 5:52/13:49min  
//8.6: API Front End Client - Programming with Text
//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zr8j-jeU_M&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Yyn-fBtGHfN0_xCtBwUkBp&index=6




////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//package.json


/*
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "name": "project-pj",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  }
}
*/


//Second "package.json" file"
//npm init
/*
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "name": "project-pj",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
*/
```